# Passing Variables into a class once as setup vs passing it multiple times? C#

Tags: c#, performance, parameters, global-variables

Right, so I'm looking for a performance impact/code style answer here so this might not be the right place to ask.

I've got a DataRow 'reader' set up from a Database result and then I extract the values into an object. Since for each variable I want to check for null values and return a 'failure' value if it is null I have to perform the check:

```
try
{
    if (reader[property] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        var = reader[property];
    }
    else
    {
        var = failureValue;
    }
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
     // DISPLAY ERROR ABOUT NO VALUE CALLED Property
     var = failureValue;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // DISPLAY GENERIC ERROR ABOUT VALUE
    var = failureValue;
}
```

In my current situation I perform that check 47 times in one class so I moved the code into a method and then called it. Its important to note I put it in a superclass for my data access classes so every one could use it.

My question now, when I created this method I originally passed in the full DataRow 'reader' every time the method was called. Should I make a static variable within the superclass and set it when I set up the 'reader'? Thereby, allowing the method to access a static variable within itself and not having to perform the passing of the full reader every time? Or is it slower to change it over like [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/declaring-a-variables-locally-vs-globally-effect-on-performance.186915/) suggests?

EDIT: As both the first answer and comment have questioned, the variable does need to be static as the superclass is never initialised itself, just inherited from.

Comment: Pass what your method needs to fulfill its task. Pass via initialization (e.g. constructor) if the complete class needs the dependency. In your case its absolulety fine to pass the same reader on every call, it does not have any performance-impacts - even *if* they were so little, you might have other problems than those nano-seconds. You could of course also add a property which you set once before any call to the method, doesn´t need to be `static`.

Comment: So if i were to do: setReader(reader) and then call that before any call to the extract method, that would be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance-perspective it makes no difference at all (maybe some nano-seconds, but you won´t care for that) if you pass the reader again and again or store it locally into a variable. In contrast to what´s said in the post you´ve mentioned there is no difference on where an object is stored between decalaring it in a method or in the class itself. If it is stored on the stack or heap is determined by other means.

However from an API-perspective you should ask yourself if the dependency (in your case the reader) is needed for *all* members (or at least a few) of your class or just one single. I suggest passing the dependencies where you really need them.

Another appraoch is to set the dependency by a setter before calling your method the first time:

```
var instance = new MyType();
instance.SetReader(reader);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) instance.DoSomething();
```

As per your EDIT: only because your base-class isn´t instantiated doesn´t mean all it´s members should be `static`. Actually your base-class *is instantiated*, whenever you create a new instance of one of its child-classes (which cab be converted to the base-class though). So you can just use a usual instance-member that is inherited by all deriving classes.

You may have a look at [dependecy injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass instances rather than using a class-level, static variable.

The reason is because you want to maintain tight control over the scope and thus lifetime of your variables.  You don't want them to exist any longer than they need to or be available outside of the scope within which they're needed.

Lets leave aside for the moment the fact that a data reader -- e.g. `SqlDataReader` -- implements the disposable pattern; you would still be making your application unnecessarily complicated.  It may not seem to matter that much for a small application with relatively few classes, methods, and variables, but small applications have a habit of growing into larger, more-complex ones.

As I alluded to above, data readers like `SqlDataReader` implement `IDisposable`, which means that the way you are *supposed* to use instances of them is within a `using` statement:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // ... do stuff
}
```

That way, the reader is guaranteed to be disposed and garbage collected before the block exits, even in the event of an exception.  What's important to note is that the variable `reader` *only exists within the scope of the `using` block*.  Narrower scope means not only is it easier to read your code and know what's happening where and when, but it also guarantees that your variables will be garbage collected when they are no longer needed.

Think about it: if you had a static, class-level variable, when would it be garbage collected?  Not until the application exits.  That is very hard to debug in cases where you're having memory issues.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, currently I'm using a web service to return me a new DataTable from a query and then I'm iterating over the rows using dataTable.row[i] and then passing that to the method. When i exit the method to return me the data, the datatable is available for garbage collection, only the last row may be left when passed to the superclass. i could get around this by adding a clearReader() method to null out the reference and allow full garbage collection?